# button events not fire in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

The if (!Page.IsPostBack) is always false went the page loads after i click a linkbutton and it never goes into the linkbutton event. Desperately need help! Googled as much as I can. I am kinda new to asp

This is the code that i have in server:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetDefaultView();

        }

    }


    private void SetDefaultView()
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }


    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }



    protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    }
```

// and below..

```
<td>
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Tab1</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton2_Click">Tab2</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the code part of a dynamically loaded UserControl? If so, in what stage of the asp.net lifecycle are you adding the UserControl?

If that is not the case, how do you access the Page?

Comment: Its MVC ASP.Net and added the buttons using the toolbox and double clicked on the button to get to the event

Comment: If it is asp.net MVC then i would avoid mixing technologies. The server code you have posted shows asp.net WebForms code. In MVC you would build "RESTful" Requests / urls that are mapped to Controller.Actions.